# Call deep child function in App.js (grand grand parent) component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I had a case when I need to call a child function in my App.js component.

The short schema look like this :

[image]

Where I need to call the function() from the App.js, and the the function triggers something directly inside the Child 3 component.

I'm avoiding using function props drilling from the parent where this could be another problem in the future.

I tried to use Redux to dispatch the function into store, but Redux doesn't allow non-object properties to be stored.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are probably not following a best practive doing this way. however *use refs* - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs

Comment: what `non-object properties to be stored` are you trying to store?

Comment: @AkshayM I tried to store function, but unable to accomplish in redux with error message :  “Reducers may not dispatch actions”.

Comment: @LucaFabbri but isn't these cases are pretty common? Let say I need to change my parent header color by the click of a button somewhere in the child hierarchy, so shouldn't I pass up the function/value to the parent component? I'm pretty new to react and redux, so this concept might not be the best

Comment: @HilalArsa maybe you can provide a Codesandbox example? It's not easy to get what you are trying to achieve